# Use printf to format list that is uneven

Tags: linux, awk

I have a small list of student grades, I need to format it them side by side depending on the gender of the student. So one column is Male the other Female. The problem is the list doesn't go male female male female, it is uneven.

I've tried using printf to format the output so the 2 columns are side by side, but the format is ruined because of the uneven list.

```
Name Gender Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
AA M 20 15 35
BB F 22 17 44
CC F 19 14 25
DD M 15 20 42
EE F 18 22 30
FF M 0 20 45
```

This is the list I am talking about ^^

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Male" " Female"} {if (NR!=1) {if ($2 == "M") {printf "%-s %-s %-s", $3, $4, $5} else if ($2 == "F") {printf "%s %s %s\n", $3, $4 ,$5}}}' text.txt
```

So I'm getting results like

```
Male Female
20 15 35 22 17 44
19 14 25
15 20 42 18 22 30 
0 20 45
```

But I want it like this:

```
Male Female
20 15 35 22 17 44
15 20 42 19 14 25
0 20 45 18 22 30
```

I haven't added separators yet I'm just trying to figure this out, not sure if it would be better to put the marks into 2 arrays depending on gender then printing them out.

Comment: Is it possible with your file to store 2 successive records and then to test which one is M or F, or more than 2 successive M or F are possible?

Comment: Can you show how the output should look when the number of M and F are uneven

Answer (score 1):

another solution tries to address if M/F is not unity

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print "Male\tFemale"} 
       NR>1  {k=$2;$1=$2="";sub(/ +/,"");
              if(k=="M") m[++mc]=$0; else f[++fc]=$0} 
       END   {max=mc>fc?mc:fc; 
              for(i=1;i<=max;i++) print (m[i]?m[i]:"-") "\t" (f[i]?f[i]:"-")}' file |
  column -ts$'\t'

Male      Female
20 15 35  22 17 44
15 20 42  19 14 25
0 20 45   18 22 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
awk 'BEGIN{format="%2s %2s %2s %2s\n";printf("Male     Female\n"); }NR>1{if (s) { if ($2=="F") {printf(format, s, $3, $4, $5);} else {printf(format, $3,$4,$5,s);} s=""} else {s=sprintf("%2s %2s %2s", $3, $4, $5)}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `awk`

```
awk '
        BEGIN {
                print "Male\t\tFemale"
        }
        NR > 1 {
                I = ++G[$2]
                A[$2 FS I] = sprintf("%2d %2d %2d", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF)
        }
        END {
                M = ( G["M"] > G["F"] ? G["M"] : G["F"] )
                for ( i = 1; i <= M; i++ )
                        print A["M" FS i] ? A["M" FS i] : OFS, A["F" FS i] ? A["F" FS i] : OFS
        }
' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ee '1c\Male Female' -e 'N;s/^.. M (.*)\n.. F(.*)/\1\2/;s/^.. F(.*)\n.. M (.*)/\2\1/' file
```

Change the header line. Then compare a pair of lines and re-arrange them as appropriate.